# Cannot access installed packages from npm. receive "Command not found"

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, path

When trying to access a package or cli downloaded through npm (globally or locally), I receive an error that it cannot be found.

I have tried changing the PATH in the .bash_profile
I have tried uninstalling node and npm completely and reinstalling
I have tried removing the .bash_profile and replacing it with a new one. 
I am out of ideas here and have been at this for hours.

```
npm get prefix returns /usr/local

echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

```
npm install express
```

`express` should not return an error.
it returns command not found

EDIT:

on furthur inspection it seems the package is created in /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/express regardless of the npm prefix.

all of my items in the usr/local/bin seem to work in the command line. So I guess my question is now how do i get node to install global packages in that folder vs where it's installing now?

Comment: How about using npx to run a npm command locally?

Comment: while that works good for the short term, I would really like to figure out what is going wrong here